# Automatic Formatting of US Phone Numbers: +1 (435) 777-8574 Format

Tags: javascript

I want to the number to be in US format `+1 (456) 785 -3424`. But when I add `1` in front it is printed again and again

```
function numberReg(event) {
  let input = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  let NumValue = "";

  if (input.length >= 1) {
    NumValue += "+1 ";
    if (input.length >= 4) {
      NumValue += "(" + input.substring(0, 3) + ") ";
      if (input.length >= 7) {
        NumValue += input.substring(3, 6) + " -" + input.substring(6, 10);
      } else {
        NumValue += input.substring(3, 6);
      }
    } else {
      NumValue += input.substring(0, 3);
    }
  }
  event.target.value = NumValue;
}
```

[image: Here is the output]

All the code is working fine except when 1 put at front

Comment: You're putting `+1` at the beginning any time the value is not empty. So you add it even if it's already there. You should check whether the number begins with `+1` before adding it.

Comment: There are  some good input masking widgets out there, I suggest you use them. You can also use `<input type="tel">` for telephone numbers, and the browser will handle the formatting automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a phone number as a user types using pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058927/format-a-phone-number-as-a-user-types-using-pure-javascript)

Comment: The same problem if I check the number

Answer (score 0):

You could format the number two ways.

If the length of the number is less than 11, default to a simple "(xxx) xxx-xxxx" format. Else, format with the country code at the beginning, accounting for the offset.

```js
const MIN_PHONE_LENGTH = 10;

const phoneNumberFormatter = (num) => {
  const d = num.trim().replace(/\D/g, ''); // Digits
  if (d.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }
  const o = d.length - MIN_PHONE_LENGTH; // Delta or offset 
  if (o > 0) {
    return `+${d.slice(0, o)} (${d.slice(o, o + 3)}) ${d.slice(o + 3, o + 6)}-${d.slice(o + 6, o + 10)}`;
  }
  return `(${d.slice(0, 3)}) ${d.slice(3, 6)}-${d.slice(6, 10)}`; // Default
}

function formatPhoneNumber({ target }) {
  target.value = phoneNumberFormatter(target.value);
}

formatPhoneNumber({ target: document.querySelector('#phone') }); // Init
```

```html
<!-- +1 (456) 785-3424 -->
<input type="text" id="phone" oninput=formatPhoneNumber(event) value="4567853424" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I started from substring 0 instead of 1, which is why 1 was repeating

```js
function numberReg(event) {
  let input = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  let NumValue = "";

  if (input.length >= 1) {
    NumValue += "+1 ";

    if (input.length >= 5) {
      NumValue += "(" + input.substring(1, 4) + ") ";

      if (input.length >= 8) NumValue += input.substring(4, 7) + " -" + input.substring(7, 11); 
      else NumValue += input.substring(4, 7);

    } 
    
    else NumValue += input.substring(1, 4);
  }
  event.target.value = NumValue;
}
```