# Number format for Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm doing number formatting in Angular JS for account numbers for a banking application.

How can I implement account format 11-02980-1. I want the delimiter (-) to be added automatically to the input text when some adds the numbers (11029801). i.e when i type 11, the delimiter (-) is added and then 02980, another delimiter is added and then lastly 1

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A directive to format phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057481/a-directive-to-format-phone-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Is this what you were looking for?

Try this snippet:

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
MyApp.controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController($scope) {
 $scope.accNumber = '';
 $scope.previousAccNumber = '';
 $scope.editAccountNumber = function (accNumber) {
  if ($scope.previousAccNumber.length > accNumber.length) {
   $scope.previousAccNumber = accNumber;
   return accNumber;
  }
  accNumber = accNumber.replace(/-/g, '');
  var classA = accNumber.slice(0, 2);
  var classB = accNumber.slice(2, 7);
  var classC = accNumber.slice(7, 8);
  var finalNumber = [];

  if (classA && classA.length == 2) {
   finalNumber.push(classA, "-");
  } else {
   return classA;
  }

  if (classB && classB.length == 5) {
   finalNumber.push(classB, "-");
  } else {
   return classA + "-" + classB;
  }

  if (classC && classC.length == 1) {
   finalNumber.push(classC);
  }
  $scope.previousAccNumber = finalNumber.join('');
  return finalNumber.join('');
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <input id="accNumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter Account Number" ng-model="accNumber" ng-change="accNumber = editAccountNumber(accNumber)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi could you please have a full implementation for this with what should be the tags for the html file. I tried the following but it failed  <input id ="accNumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter Account Number" ng-change="editAccountNumber(accNumber)"/>

Comment: @IppezRobertsTrevorzMarxwell Try my new snippet

Comment: Am still having challenges implementing this because some of the input fields already have ng-model bind to it.

Is it possible to have more than one ng-model on one input field e.g ng-model="formData.glCode" ng-model="accNumber " ng-change="accNumber = editAccountNumber(accNumber)"? Because all this input fields where i want to apply this have ng-models already and i also need to use my ng-model="accNumber "

Thanks